# Understanding the Seiberg-Witten equations in dimension $3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections, gauge-theory, spinor, seiberg-witten

I am trying to understand the dimensional reduction of Seiberg-Witten equations from dimension $4$ to $3$, more specifically my concern is about ellipticity of the new equations in dimension $3$ under temporal gauge. I am reading the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/dg-ga/9606003.pdf. Look at lemma 1.2 at page 12. Here's my concern: according to my understanding in the deformation complex,

\begin{align*}
0\rightarrow\Omega^0(Y,i\mathbb{R})\oplus\Omega^1(Y,i\mathbb{R})\oplus\Gamma(S\otimes L)\rightarrow \Omega^0(Y,i\mathbb{R})\oplus\Omega^1(Y,i\mathbb{R})\oplus\Gamma(S\otimes L)\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
The $\Omega^0(Y,i\mathbb{R})$ on the right hand side (rhs) is due to linearization related to the gauge action, the $\Omega^1(Y,i\mathbb{R})$ on the left hand side (lhs) is for the change in connection, $\Omega^1(Y,i\mathbb{R})$ on rhs is supposed to be $\Omega^2(Y,i\mathbb{R})$ but it's same as $\Omega^1(Y,i\mathbb{R})$ using Hodge-star, that's where $d$ of change in connection should lie and the $\Gamma(S\otimes L)$s are for the linearization of the Dirac, but where does the $\Omega^0(Y,i\mathbb{R})$ on the lhs come from? If someone can explain briefly what's happening here, that would be very helpful.

Comment: 1-forms on R x Y take the shape a(t) + b(t) dt, where a(t) is a time-dependent 1-form on Y and b(t) is a time-dependent function on Y. The term you're asking about corresponds to b

Comment: @mme It would have been the case if this was a normal reduction but we are on temporal gauge so, $b(t)=0$, hence I thought this term shouldn't appear. At the end of the day we have to prove that the equations on a $3$-manifold is elliptic and the gauge group is Map$(Y,S^1)$ or am I making a mistake?

Comment: You are right, my comment is not on the right track. I find that section difficult to parse, but the relevant point is basically linear algebra. $T$ gives a self-adjoint operator $\Omega^1 \oplus \Gamma \to \Omega^1 \oplus \Gamma$, but it is not Fredholm, because it vanishes on the tangent space to the gauge group action at the given point. This contributes an infinite-dimensional space to the kernel.

Because this is self-adjoint, this also contributes an infinite-dimensional space to the cokernel. To correct for both, you need to introduce a copy of $\Omega^0$ in both domain and codomain.

Comment: At the smooth manifold level, if $G$ acts freely on $M$ so that $T_x(M/G) = T_xM/d\mu_x(T_e G)$ ($\mu_x: G \to M$ the group action on $x$), if $f: M/G \to \Bbb R$ is some function, its Hessian lifts to $TM = T(M/G) \oplus TG$ as $\text{Hess}(f) \oplus 0$. To focus on nondegeneracy of $\text{Hess}(f)$ downstairs, we can add the symmetric gauge fixing condition to the Hessian upstairs, adding $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & d\mu_x \\ d\mu_x^* & 0 \end{pmatrix}$; then the modified Hessian upstairs is nondegenerate if and only if $\text{Hess}(f)$ is.